# Autoprefixer generically adds prefixes to browser-specific extensions

Tags: css, autoprefixer

how to block autoprefixer from adding -webkit prefixes to a Mozilla specific extension ?

Here are some examples to make my point :

```
.custom-range::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none
}
```

-webkit-transition has nothing to do here as it is a Mozilla specific selector (::-moz-range-thumb).

Another crazy output happens with keyframes and transitions, as Autoprefixer creates useless variants

```
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s ease-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.1s ease-out;
```

Instead of just

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.1s ease-out;
      transition: box-shadow 0.1s ease-out;
```

How to fix this ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like a bug, not a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force Autoprefixer to ignore specific blocks of CSS by using "Control Comments" (their words). It looks pretty flexible.

```
.className {
  /* autoprefixer: off */
  something: not-prefixed;
}
```

Here's the [documentation](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#disabling).

But you might also want to submit a bug as what you're seeing could be filtered out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know if this behavior was due to me or to Autoprefixer.
Heading right away to Github Issues. Thanks